# Why are hyperbolic trigonometric functions avoided in (my) high school and early post-secondary school?

Tags: soft-question, education, hyperbolic-functions

I remember seeing hyperbolic trigonometric functions (sinh, cosh, tanh, etc.) in my precalculus textbook back in high school and see them today in my calculus textbook. However, I have not had a formal introduction to them in my education. This may just be with me, but I would like to know if there is a reason as to why they are avoided.

Comment: Political correctness, not enough time, lower quality students, more important topics, lousy teachers, common core chains, students more interested in instagram and kik ...

Comment: I have often wondered about that.  An unfounded, undergraduate hypothesis is that right-triangle trig is more obviously applicable to physical applications that highschoolers/lower-undergrads would understand.  A more likely (unfortunately) idea is the one Amzoti mentioned.

Comment: when I teach calculus II I personally make a point of comparing and contrasting the hyperbolic verses trigonometric substitutions. In fact, the duality of the formulas brings added insight to both sides. But, alas, I am alone in this.

Comment: As with many historical mysteries, this goes back to behind-the-scenes manipulations by Rodrigo Borgia, father of Lucrezia and Cesare: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Tordesillas

Comment: Hyperbolic functions are skipped in a lot of university calculus sequences as well.  An argument for doing so is that, in terms of applications, they turn up very little outside of physics and some branches of engineering.  Most people can really go happily through their lives without worrying about hyperbolic functions or complex numbers.  Consequently, they generally get introduced "if there's time" in first-year university math, but otherwise get covered in much detail in "upper-division courses" (with the usual "of course you've already seen this...") I don't approve either >:/ ...

Comment: I think it should be said, though, that the omission of topics and weakness of student preparation is a relative matter.  There has been a certain amount of "dumbing-down" of the school curricula (at least in the U.S.) so that even experience with math much beyond basic (standard) algebra and plane geometry is sorely lacking in high-school graduates.  (Don't get me started on how many students can't write a proof.)  On the other hand, the number of people who have had at least some exposure to trigonometry and first-sem. calculus is probably at a historical high.

Answer (score 1):

One reason may be that the input of hyperbolic functions is often interpreted as the area partially bounded by a hyperbolic curve, while regular trigonometric functions take an angle as an input. Even though hyperbolic functions have lots of nice properties, teachers may not see them as as important as regular trigonometric functions, since the area is useful only in specific scenarios, for example bridge construction.